# JSON-LD Labels used as Keywords

Tags: html, blogger, json-ld

In my JSON-LD Markup I get the Labels in Blogspot as Keywords with this code:

```
&quot;keywords&quot;: &quot;<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'><data:label.name/><b:if cond='not data:label.isLast'>,</b:if>
```

But some of the keywords are just for the organization of the blog posts for example such as up, down, middle... Is there a way to change the code so that these keywords are not shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter labels to except specific labels:

```
"keywords": "<b:loop values='data:post.labels where (label => label.name not in ["up", "down", "middle", "..etc"])' var='label'><data:label.name/><b:if cond='not data:label.isLast'>,</b:if></b:loop>"
```

Comment: Sure, I will do this!